# Substitution of parameter value SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, if-statement, substitution

What am I missing on my query below?

When I'm passing parameter for (@Status) **'All'** , there were no results even though the **@status** parameter condition is satisfied.

Since when I pass 'All' it will be changed to (un-assigned, assigned). But when I'm passing Assigned/ Un-Assigned directly, it works fine.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_File_Search]

  @Uploaded AS  INT = null,
  @File_Name AS VARCHAR(150) = null,
  @Upload_DT AS DATETIME = null,
  @Status AS VARCHAR(150) = null,
  @St1 AS VARCHAR(15) = null,
  @St2 AS VARCHAR(15) = null


AS

If @Status = 'All'

BEGIN

 SET @St1 = 'Un-Assigned'

 SET @St2 = 'Assigned'

 END

 ELSE

 BEGIN

 SET @St1 = @Status

 SET @St2 = @Status

 END


    --ON UPLOAD DATE
Begin 

if @Uploaded= 1 

Begin

SELECT [FILE_ID],[FILE_NAME], [UPLOAD_DT] FROM [dbo].[FILE]

WHERE  (
            [FILE_NAME] like '%' + @File_Name + '%'

            OR @File_Name IS NULL

            )
    AND (

            [UPLOAD_DT] between @Upload_DT + '00:00:00' and  @Upload_DT + '23:59:59'

            OR @Upload_DT IS NULL OR @Upload_DT = ''

            )
    AND (
    [STATUS] IN (@St1,@St2)

Order by Upload_DT desc

END


-- ON OR BEFORE UPLOAD DATE

if @Uploaded=2

Begin

SELECT [FILE_ID],[FILE_NAME], [UPLOAD_DT]

FROM [cobind].[FILE]

WHERE  (

            [FILE_NAME] like '%' + @File_Name + '%'

            OR @File_Name IS NULL

            )

    AND (

            [UPLOAD_DT] between @Upload_DT + '00:00:00' and  @Upload_DT + '23:59:59'

            OR [UPLOAD_DT] < @Upload_DT 

            OR @Upload_DT IS NULL OR @Upload_DT = ''

            )

    AND (
            [STATUS] IN (@St1,@St2)
        )
Order by Upload_DT desc 

END

-- ON OR AFTER UPLPOAD DATE

if @Uploaded=3

Begin

SELECT [FILE_ID], [FILE_NAME], [UPLOAD_DT]

FROM [dbo].[FILE]

WHERE  (
            [FILE_NAME] like '%' + @File_Name + '%'

            OR @File_Name IS NULL 

            )
    AND (
            [UPLOAD_DT] between @Upload_DT + '00:00:00' and  @Upload_DT + '23:59:59'

            OR [UPLOAD_DT] > @Upload_DT 

            OR @Upload_DT IS NULL OR @Upload_DT = ''

            )

    AND (
            [STATUS] IN (@St1,@St2)
        )

Order by Upload_DT desc

END

END
```

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` keyword works with either a subquery or a list. When you create the list of values in the `SET @Status` statement, you are actually creating a string. The query will try to look for the specific string, and since that string does not exist in the column being searched, there won't be any results.

You can work around this by using dynamic SQL. Basically, create a variable to hold the part related to `@Status`, create the query itself as an `NVARCHAR` string and append your variable clause to it. Finally, use `sp_executesql` to run the query, something like this:

```
If @Status = 'All'
SET @Status = '(''Un-Assigned'',''Assigned'')'

declare @query nvarchar(1000) = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CoM_REPO] WHERE [STATUS] IN ' + @Status + ' Order by UploadDATE desc' 

exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your solution, looks great. However, I have three conditions and I can't afford to create different combinations to satisfy my conditions. Let's say if the @uploaded is not equal to 1 I will execute a different where clause. With this the if statement will be plenty

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but if you figured out a way to solve your problem then that's good!

Comment: Hi please see my updated query in my question. Kindly see if this one is a good solution. Thanks a lot. Apologize as well as I'm a newbie in development. Thanks a lot my friend!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you are only changing the table name in the case where `@upLoaded = 2`. The rest of the query is the same, so you could just create another variable to hold the table name and do the same thing that was done for the `@Status` clause.

Comment: Sorry, just realised there is also difference in another clause. Again, you could extract that clause into another variable also, and make the query 'even more dynamic', but your method seems OK too

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs my friend. That's a typo error, I don't intend to change the table name. :)
If it is not too much to ask, can you site me an example of your suggestion? thanks again.:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error message ? 
I guess its because your query says [STATUS] IN (@Status) , meaning () are already there, so if you pass Assigned , it would be coming as [STATUS] IN ('Assigned'), whereas when you are passing 'All', it may be coming as  [STATUS] IN ((''Un-Assigned'',''Assigned'')) with double brackets, just try to remove the brackets.

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors. I also tried to remove the brackets and tried everything like  'Un-Assigned,Assigned' but still didn't work.